# Have installed Dash on macOS, but gives error while running the script

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying to run dash through Jupiter notebook on macOS. It does get imported and when I try to run app.run_server command it fails. it gives me the following error

> [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just specify the explicit host name in the `app.py`
Default hostname causes such issue

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.server.run(port=8000, host='127.0.0.1')
```